# How To manage multiple DataProvider in TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, inheritance, testng, dataprovider

I am working on TestNG. I have a class which has around thousands of dataProviders methods. It looks like this:

```
Class X {
    // some bootstrap code 

    @DataProvider(name = "test1")
    public static Object[][] primeNumbers() {

    }

    DataProvider(name = "test2")
    public static Object[][] primeNumbers() {

    }

    DataProvider(name = "test3")
    public static Object[][] primeNumbers() {

    }


    ///// some more data providers 

    DataProvider(name = "test100")
    public static Object[][] primeNumbers() {

    }
}
```

This class file is growing long. I want to break it into small classes, so that it look small and maintainable. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding,

1. If this class X having the data providers to test one class only, then It means your class is doing so many things, If this is the case then It is against to SRP(Single responsibility Principle) for that class. In that case you should refactor the main class, if possible.
2. If the class X is used to having the data providers for more than one classes (may be for all classes in your project), then you can break it and make the different data provider classes for each specific classes and put the data providers for that specific class only.
3. If your class to be tested are small enough, then you can write the data providers in the same test class without writing the dedicated seprate data provider class for each class.

You can choose any option as per your project's requirement. Hope It may help you.